# Hibernate Framework - Display records after adding (or affecting) data of the database

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm new to Hibernate framework and having 3 layers of code for adding a new `Category` object to the database, say:

**The DAL class with its constructor:**

```
public class ImportProductDAL {
    private Session session;

    public ImportProductDAL() {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    }
...
}
```

My method for getting the list of `Category`:

```
public ArrayList<Category> categoryList(){
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Category", Category.class);
        ArrayList<Category> categories = (ArrayList<Category>) query.list();
        return categories;
    }
```

And a method for creating a new `Category`:

```
public boolean createCategory(Category c) {
        session.persist(c);
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
        return session.getTransaction().getStatus() == TransactionStatus.COMMITTED;
    }
```

**My BLL class contains similar methods such as:**

```
public ArrayList<Category> catgoryList(){
        return ipDAL.categoryList();
}
```

And:

```
public boolean createCategory(Category c){
        return ipDAL.createCategory(c);
}
```

**In my UI class:**

```
private void categoryList() {
        table.setModel(model(ipBLL.catgoryList()));
}
```

And

```
private DefaultTableModel model(ArrayList list) {
        String[] columnNames = {"ID", "Category Name", "Description"};
        Object[][] data = new Object[list.size()][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Category category = (Category) list.get(i);
            data[i][0] = category.getCatagoryID();
            data[i][1] = category.getName();
            data[i][2] = category.getDescription();
        }
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        return model;
}
```

And an event when I click the "Add" button:

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        if (!txtCategory.getText().trim().equals("") && !txtDescription.getText().trim().equals("")) {
            Category newCategory = new Category();
            newCategory.setName(txtCategory.getText());
            newCategory.setDescription(txtDescription.getText());

            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Add new category?",
                    "Confimation",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                if (ipBLL.createCategory(newCategory)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                            "Category added successfully!");
                    categoryList();
                }
            }

        }
}
```

I am expecting whenever I click on the button, it will add a new record to the database and display the list on my table in the UI class. It did add a new record to the database but didn't display the updated table. I have to run my program again to see the result I want. It could be the usage of `flush()` or `clear()` method.

I have read bunch of questions on stackoverflow but it seems like I have tried everything I could.

What am I missing here? Please guide me.

Comment: You open a transaction in `ImportProductDAL`. Is this transaction ever committed?

Comment: I'm not getting what you are asking